# Resigned ipa do not install on ios devices

Tags: ios, xcode, ipa

My organization has developer account (not enterprise) and have added me as a "team member" to the organizations team account and shared the developer certificate and development provisioning profile(includes 1 device). Using those, I could develop an app, archive and created an IPA from XCode (selected method of distribution as "Development") and exported to a folder on disk. When exported I have the following files created on my disk

- DistributionSummary.plist
- ExportOptiona.plist
- manifest.pList
- Packaging.log
- app.ipa

The admin of my organization wants to resign this ipa to distribute to app store and followed all the steps mentioned below, with distribution certificate and dist. provisioning profile (app store). The resigned ipa is then distributed(OTA) to users and it will not install on their phones.

---

**I followed the below steps to re-sign our ipa**

## unzip the app

unzip -q *.ipa

## Remove the old signature

rm -rf Payload/*.app/_CodeSignature/

## Replace embedded provisioning profile

cp "XXXXXXXXXX_distribution.mobileprovision" Payload/*.app/embedded.mobileprovision

## Extract entitlements from app

codesign -d --entitlements :entitlements.plist Payload/*.app/

## Re-sign embedded frameworks

codesign -f -s "iPhone Distribution: Certificate Name. (ABC44343XZ)" --entitlements entitlements.plist Payload/*.app/Frameworks/*

## Re-sign the app (with entitlements)

codesign -f -s "iPhone Distribution: Certificate Name. (ABC44343XZ)" --entitlements entitlements.plist Payload/*.app/

## Zip re-signed app

zip -qr resigned.ipa Payload

## Cleanup

rm entitlements.plist

rm -r Payload/

---

Can I re-sign an app from a developer to distribute to app store? Can somebody tell me where I am going wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have resigned the IPA for delivery to the App Store, but then you are trying to deliver the app directly to users; this wont work.  You have to upload the app to the App Store and submit it to Apple for review. Once approved users can install from the App Store. To distribute directly to users you need to sign for ad-hoc distribution and include a provisioning profile that has all of the device identifiers that you want to run the app on.

Comment: Thanks Paul. After re-signing the app, I tried to upload resigned ipa to App store connect via Application Loader and after about 30-40 mins I get the following error message ERROR ITMS-90164: "Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. The entitlements in your app bundle signature do not match the ones that are contained in the provisioning profile. According to the provisioning profile, the bundle contains a key value that is not allowed: 'true' for the key 'get-task-allow' in 'Payload/xxxxxxx.app/xxxxxxxxx'". Do I have to make any changes during ipa resigning process, like edit entitlements file ?

Comment: [Update] I edited the entitlements file for the key 'get-task-allow' to be false during re-signing process and uploaded to re-signed app to app store connect using Application Loader and it successfully uploaded. But then, when I log in to the App Store Connect, I do not see the build there. Any ideas???

Comment: [Update] I received an email from apple with the following issue to be fixed "Invalid Swift Support - The SwiftSupport folder is missing. Rebuild your app using the current public (GM) version of Xcode and resubmit it." Can anyone help me here?

Comment: Why are you doing all of this manual work instead of just getting Xcode to deliver the app to the App Store for you?

Answer (score 0):

Note: I'm answering what you're saying in the comments

> [Update] I received an email from apple with the following issue to be fixed "Invalid Swift Support - The SwiftSupport folder is missing. Rebuild your app using the current public (GM) version of Xcode and resubmit it." Can anyone help me here?

I can't do it directly on comments as I don't have enough reputation.

When you unzip the .ipa the first time, you should see at least four folders: one is the **Payload** (where you do all the signing operations, and changes regarding configuration), **Symbols**, **BCSymbolMaps** and a **SwiftSupport** folder. When you do the zip you have to add also the **SwiftSupport** folder to the .ipa:

```
zip -qr yourNewApp.ipa Payload/ SwiftSupport/
```

After doing this, you upload through Application Loader or you can validate your .ipa running this:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application\ Loader.app/Contents/Frameworks/ITunesSoftwareService.framework/Support/altool -v -f yourNewApp.ipa -u yourItunesConnectUser@mail.com
```